# Swagger - dynamic default value

Tags: .net-core, swagger

I would like to get the default value set for Swagger UI. The value should be taken from appsettings.json as it might get changed for different environments. How would I do that?

Have this:

```
app.MapPost("/route", async (string something) => await Task.Delay(0));
```

What I expect:

`something` variable should have default value when using swagger ui. It's value should be set to whatever appsettings json value is.

Answer (score 0):

To do that we can define `OperationFilter` that will be associated with `DefaultValueAttribute`.

so firstly, change your minimal api method to have default value:

```
app.MapPost("/route", async ([DefaultValue("__configuration__SomeValue")]string something) => await Task.Delay(0));
```

then define `OperationFilter` that dynamically replace defined value with that in your appsettings:

```
public class OperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public OperationFilter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in operation.Parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Schema.Default is OpenApiString @default &&
                @default.Value.StartsWith("__configuration__"))
            {
                parameter.Schema.Default = new OpenApiString(_configuration.GetValue<string>(@default.Value.Replace("__configuration__", string.Empty)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know whether it's the best way to do it but it just works, tried out